# Как вывести значение функции, написанной после события onchange на js?

Tags: javascript, onchange

```
$('#select-function').on('change' function selected() {
  if ($(this).val() == 1) {
    var qwerty = 10;
    return(qwerty);
  }
  else if ($(this).val() == 2) {
    var qwerty = 20;
    return(qwerty);
  }
  else if ($(this).val() == 3) {
    var qwerty = 30;
    return(qwerty);
  }
  else if ($(this).val() == 4) {
    var qwerty = 40;
    return(qwerty);
  }
  else {
    var qwerty = 50;
    return(qwerty);
  }
})
var xxx = selected();
```

Comment: а куда именно Вы хотите вывести это значение?

Comment: Я хочу вывести значение в общий код и использовать переменную в формуле подсчета. Просто в зависимости от значения списка меняется значение переменной.

Comment: Я бы мог написать формулу в начале функции и проблема решилась бы, но у меня таких переменных целых пять, поэтому нужно вывести в общий код.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Алексей Шиманский объяснил Вам, какая может быть логика в решении. Я приведу наглядный пример. Сначала Вы пишете некую общую функцию для вычислений, куда потом в качестве параметра будет передаваться значение из селекта. А уже после события onchange вызываете её.

```js
function selected(num) {
  /* здесь какие-то вычисления, например: */
  let result = num*2+15;
  console.log(result);
}

$('#select-function').on('change', function() {
  let qwerty = 0;
  if ($(this).val() == 1) {
    qwerty = 10;
  }
  else if ($(this).val() == 2) {
    qwerty = 20;
  }
  else if ($(this).val() == 3) {
    qwerty = 30;
  }
  else if ($(this).val() == 4) {
    qwerty = 40;
  }
  else {
    qwerty = 50;
  }
  selected(qwerty);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="select-function">
  <option value="">Сделайте выбор</option>
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
  <option value="3">3</option>
  <option value="4">4</option>
  <option value="5">5</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

После события никак. Да это и не нужно. Достаточно создать функцию, например с именем `calc` и передать его как коллекции для события change. В итоге там всё будет считаться при каждом изменении селекта

Или передать общую функцию, в которой будет несколько: например одна пересчитывает, вторая что-то где-то перерендывает